# Compiling a java class into a ColdFusion CFX giving errors

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a ColdFusion CFX using java.  I am starting very simple to make sure everything works, but so far nothing has.

This is my java class (employee.java)

```
public class employee implements CustomTag 
{ 
    public void processRequest( Request request, Response response ) 
    throws Exception 
    { 
        String strName = request.getAttribute( "NAME" ) ; 
        response.write( "Hello, " + strName ) ; 
    } 
}
```

I am trying to compile it with the following command:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\javac -classpath C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib\cfx.jar employee.java
```

But when I do, I get the following errors:

```
employee.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
public class employee implements CustomTag
                                 ^
  symbol: class CustomTag
employee.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        public void processRequest( Request request, Response response )
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Request
  location: class employee
employee.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        public void processRequest( Request request, Response response )
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class employee
3 errors
```

I tried moving the cfx.jar file into the same directory as my java class but this had no effect.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does this buy you over loading your custom JARs and using `createObject()`? Curious why you're trying to create a CFX instead of just referencing your Java directly as objects.

Comment: Because I couldn't get a simple class to work either.  I was getting Incompatible Magic Value.

Comment: And now, after I finally get the CFX to compile...not really sure what I did wrong, was just fidgeting with the paths, etc...now I'm getting the same incompatible magic value with my new CFX class.

Comment: The cfx example in the adobe docs is wrong. It should be importing the `CustomTag` interface at the top of the class (and `Request` and `Response`).  Using a java IDE (instead of CLI) would explain errors like that ...

Comment: Also, in java class names traditionally start with a capital letter, i.e. Employee.java, not employee.java